# Java - how to get the stack trace from before a Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace, runnable

I had a close look at the SO "questions that may already have your answer" here and surprised not to find what I'm asking for...

When an exception occurs in (for example) the EDT, or you just want to examine the stack for whatever reason, it's trivial to find the stack back to the run() of the Runnable.  But how would you go about finding the thread (and hence stack) which ran the Runnable?  and go about finding the thread (and hence stack) which ran *that* thread's Runnable... and so on and so on...

I'm aware of Thread.getAllStackTraces()... but how might one determine which of these threads called the "current thread"?  Except "called" isn't the right word... I mean which *ran* the current thread.

Comment: Your question is not very specific, but usually it is written in the stacktrqce. How does your stacktrace look like ?

Comment: without being annoying, I'm wondering how much you know about Runnables, e.g. Runnables run using EventQueue.invokeLater().  Thread.currentThread.dumpStack() won't show you the stack further back than "run"...

Comment: `Runnable` is just an interface, you can use it in whatever way you want... Since Java 8 I use this interface from time to time for my lambdas, and this is just one example of using it without calling `invokeLater`. You don't even show any code so there's no way to give you a good answer. Your question is vague, and not only that, you also lack of humility

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Presumably this `Runnable` is one of your implementations. Just search where that is used. Is it used in too many places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have started your new thread, the original thread has moved on to doing other stuff. Getting the stack trace of what that thread is doing at a later point in time is probably irrelevant. What you want is to capture the stack as it is when a thread is started.

What you could do is to create an Exception and pass to your `Runnable` when it is created. The exception will contain the stack up to when the runnable was created.

Something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void foo() {
    final Exception starterStackTrace = new Exception();
    executor.execute(new Runnable () {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do stuff
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Thread exception
                starterStackTrace.printStackTrace(); // How thread was started
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "irrelevant"... wow, that's quite a word to use... if we're trying to diagnose how something happened (e.g. something bad), don't we have a legitimate desire to find out how a particular Runnable got run???

Comment: @mikerodent absolutely! But you are interested in the stack when the thread was started, not the stack as it is when you get the exception in the thread. Hence you need to do like this to save the stack when you create the thread.

Comment: @mikerodent Shouldn't the thread that originated the exception handle it?  It's irrelevant to the other siblings.  The parent should be waiting on the outcome if it's concerned about potential exceptions.

Comment: @KErlandsson, MadConan... yep you're both making a lot of sense!  So we pass the multi-frame stack trace on to the Runnable one way or another... works for me!

Comment: Id love to hear why this was downvoted. We actually use this method in production to log call places for asychronous methods. Is there a better way?

Comment: I assume it was someone who doesn't understand threads enough to understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

I asked this question 3 months ago now and I spent the summer, among other things, devising a whole load of tools connected with this... specifically for Jython exception-handling.  Jythonistas will understand that there are things you can do in Jython which Java would struggle with massively.

Among other things I have managed to make these tools trace a sequence of Runnables (their stack recorded/frozen in time for future listing whenever you run a new Runnable) right back to the starter thread of an app.

Another challenge I faced was making all this work not just with running an app directly, but also when doing unit testing with the Python unittest module.

I'm surprised, in truth, that Jythonistas have (to my knowledge) never raised the problem of unittest in a Jython context, for the simple reason that if ever you need to start a new thread (typically to run something in the EDT) your failure results at the end of a unittest run may be unhelpful at best.

Anyone interested in checking out (maybe improving) my stuff is welcome to download it... pls drop me a line